# Реализация специфичной очереди

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь

Собственно есть отдельный `Runnable`, в котором выполняется некоторые действия. Этот `Runnable` имеет очередь этих действий. Между выполнением этих действий есть время - `timeout`, которое должно пройти перед выполнением следующего действия. Если очередь пустая, то поток должен спать, но как только в очередь добавят новую "задачу", то `Runnable` должен проснутся и выполнить её. Я сделал класс-набросок:

```
public final class TitleHelper implements Runnable {

    private static TitleHelper instance = new TitleHelper();

    public static TitleHelper getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private TitleHelper() {
    }

    private static final Queue<Title> titleQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();


    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (titleQueue.size() > 0) {
            Title title = titleQueue.poll();
            title.show();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(title.getShowTime());
        } else {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    public void add(Title title) {
        titleQueue.offer(title);
        //при добавлении нового объекта в очередь на показ нужно разбудить спящий поток выше.
    }

}
```

Вопросы:

1. Как реализовать то, что я написал изначально(с пробуждением потока)?
2. Насколько верно я выбрал способ реализации? Какие в нём недостатки и как улучшить его?
3. Так же я понимаю, что `ArrayQeque` - `not safe thread`, как сделать синхронизацию при добавлении и удаление(`poll`), чтобы не получить исключение об изменении из другого потока?

Comment: у вас противоречие: с одной стороны, "Между выполнением этих действий есть время - timeout, которое должно пройти перед выполнением следующего действия". но с другой стороны, "Если очередь пустая, то поток должен спать, но как только в очередь добавят новую "задачу", то Runnable должен проснутся и выполнить её".
 Получается, что если записать сразу 2 задачи, то между ними должен быть заданный промежуток, а если вторую записать через микросекунду после окончания первой, то промежутка быть не должно, ну кроме той миросекунды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

   Объявить:

   ```
   private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   private Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
   ```

   Тогда сам `run` будет таким:

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
       while (true) {
           lock.lock();
           try {
               while (titleQueue.isEmpty()) 
                   // спим
                   notEmpty.await();

               Title title = titleQueue.poll();
               title.show();
               TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(title.getShowTime());
           } finally {
               lock.unlock();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   А `add`:

   ```
   public void add(Title title) {
       lock.lock();
       try {
           titleQueue.offer(title);
           // говорим, что добавили элемент; потоки, ожидающие в wait, проснутся
           notEmpty.signal();
       }
       finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Вполне жизнеспособно.
3. Либо `Lock`, как в моём примере, либо использовать какую-нить `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, оказывается всё так просто. Спасибо большое! Вопрос: в случае, если я вызову `add(title)` из основного потока, то может быть такое, что он зависнет на попытке захватить поток `lock.lock()`(ибо тот к примеру может спать из-за TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(...)) и не даст выполнять программу дальше, пока его не получит?

Comment: @Prototype-TV не, блокировки не может быть. В моём примере только 1 проблема - в методе `run` не должно быть тяжёлых тасков. Если у вас `title.show()` лёгкий, то всё ок. А иначе `run` надолго может захватить блокировку.

Comment: понял, спасибо ещё раз. Да, метод `title.show()` лёгкий, но если Вас не затруднит, можете объяснить, какая проблема могла быть, если он был бы тяжёлым?

Comment: @Prototype-TV блокировка лочится. Тогда следующий `add(title)` зависнет на `lock.lock()` пока блокировка не будет снята (пока `show` не отработает).

Comment: ага, вот оно как, в принципе я это и имел ввиду в своём первом комментарии. Спасибо за дополнительное объяснение. Всего  хорошего)

Comment: сейчас лок все равно удерживается на время `sleep()`, т.е. надо выносить из под лока его, и заодно `show()`. После этого останется только очередь, защищенная локом, которую можно действительно заменить на `BlockingQueue`. С текущей логикой можно пойти дальше и заменить тред и очередь на `singleThreadExecutor`, но может быть потом придется откатываться, если задача усложнится.

Comment: @zRrr, можно попросить Вас написать свой ответ с выносом из под лока для наглядности?

Comment: @zRrr угу, `sleep` сейчас лочит. Поэтому обработчик тасков из очереди, по-хорошему, должно в отдельном потоке их обрабатывать.

Comment: @zRrr , извините за беспокойство, так вы сможете наглядно показать то, что имели ввиду?